# VMware machine id unique?

Tags: vmware

Is the machine id for Vmware the same as for the actual computer that it is running on?

What i want to know is if it is possible to identify what computer the VMware is running on?

Lets take this scenario:

I have an application installed on my vmware

Then i install the same application on my computer that is running the vmware

Could that application theoretically identify that it is running twice on the same computer?

Comment: Not really programming related, now, is it? Voting to migrate to Super User.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe the two numbers are the same.

From various sources I've read, the machine ID can be a completely (pseudo- of course) random number chosen during the operating system install process, or it can be dependant on your hardware. But because a virtual machine uses virtual hardware, the interior of your virtual machine should resemble a different physical machine.

That's not to say that no application will be able to detect another instance of itself installed on a virtual machine. There are ways to determine if the host machine running your code is a virtual one or a physical one, but in the scope of your question I think the answer is no.